# Complex LEFT JOIN not working as expected

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

**DBMS is [intersystems-cache](/questions/tagged/intersystems-cache)!**

Here is my full query:

```
SELECT  m.Name AS MessageType, COUNT(l.name) AS MessageCount, CAST(AVG(ResponseTime) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS AvgResponseTime
FROM 
        (SELECT DISTINCT(name) FROM ENSLIB_HL7.Message) m LEFT JOIN
        (
        SELECT CAST(li.SessionId AS Bigint) AS session_id, li.name, MIN(li.TimeCreated) AS SessionStart, MAX(lo.TimeCreated) AS SessionEnd, CAST(DATEDIFF(s, MIN(li.TimeCreated), MAX(lo.TimeCreated)) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS ResponseTime
        FROM (SELECT h1.SessionId, h1.TimeCreated, $PIECE(RawContent, '|', 4), m1.name FROM ens.messageheader h1, ENSLIB_HL7.Message m1 WHERE h1.MessageBodyId = m1.id AND h1.TimeCreated > DATEADD(mi, -30, GETUTCDATE())) li
        JOIN (SELECT h2.SessionId, h2.TimeCreated FROM ens.messageheader h2, ENSLIB_HL7.Message m2 WHERE h2.MessageBodyId = m2.id AND h2.TimeCreated > DATEADD(mi, -30, GETUTCDATE())) lo
        ON li.SessionId = lo.SessionId
        GROUP BY li.SessionId
        ) l on m.name = l.name
GROUP BY l.Name
```

This gives me 4 results:

> ```
> VXU_V04   0   (null)
> ADT_A03   3   0.01
> ADT_A04   3   0.01
> ADT_A08   143 0.01
> ```

Given that there is one result with 0 records, it seems like it is working. However, if I run `SELECT DISTINCT(name) FROM ENSLIB_HL7.Message` I get 10 results:

> ```
> VXU_V04
> ADT_A08
> ACK_A08
> ADT_A03
> ACK_A03
> ADT_A04
> ACK_A04
> ACK_V04
> ADT_A01
> ACK_A01
> ```

Why don't I get ten rows with my full query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `GROUP BY` to:

```
GROUP BY m.Name
```

You are aggregating by the column in the *second* table, so you only get one row for all the `NULL` values.

Most databases would reject this syntax, but apparently Intersystems Cache allows it.

Comment: :facepalm: Thanks!

Comment: "but apparently Intersystems Cache allows it."  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯