# LEFT JOIN on static list of items?

Tags: sql, join, left-join, intersystems-cache

**DBMS is [intersystems-cache](/questions/tagged/intersystems-cache)!**

Motivation: I need to do a left join on a table so I can get the same list of message types every time, even if the result is zero or null.  Unfortunately, this is a large table so including a `SELECT DISTINCT()` is prohibitively slow.  These should never change, so I thought I'd get the list once and just join them statically.

Based on another SO question, here is what I have to replace the `SELECT DISTINCT()`:

```
    SELECT 'HS.MESSAGE.GATEWAYREGISTRATIONREQUEST' as MessageBodyClassName
    UNION SELECT 'HS.MESSAGE.MERGEPATIENTREQUEST'
    UNION SELECT 'HS.MESSAGE.PATIENTSEARCHREQUEST'
```

This returns results that look exactly as expected, identical to the Distinct query.  However, when I plug this into my JOIN statement,  all the counts come back as zero.

**Failing Query**

```
SELECT mh.MessageBodyClassName, count(l.MessageBodyClassName) as MessageCount FROM 
    (
        SELECT 'HS.MESSAGE.GATEWAYREGISTRATIONREQUEST' as MessageBodyClassName
        UNION SELECT 'HS.MESSAGE.MERGEPATIENTREQUEST'
        UNION SELECT 'HS.MESSAGE.PATIENTSEARCHREQUEST'
    ) mh LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT messageBodyClassName FROM ens.messageheader WHERE TimeCreated > DATEADD(hh, -1, GETUTCDATE())
    ) l ON mh.MessageBodyClassName = l.MessageBodyClassName
GROUP BY mh.MessageBodyClassName
```

**Failed results**

> ```
> MessageBodyClassName                  MessageCount 
> ------------------------------------- ------------ 
> HS.MESSAGE.GATEWAYREGISTRATIONREQUEST 0            
> HS.MESSAGE.MERGEPATIENTREQUEST        0            
> HS.MESSAGE.PATIENTSEARCHREQUEST       0
> ```

---

**Working Query**

```
SELECT mh.MessageBodyClassName, count(l.MessageBodyClassName) as MessageCount FROM 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT(MessageBodyClassName) FROM ens.messageheader
    ) mh LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT messageBodyClassName FROM ens.messageheader WHERE TimeCreated > DATEADD(hh, -1, GETUTCDATE())
    ) l ON mh.MessageBodyClassName = l.MessageBodyClassName
GROUP BY mh.MessageBodyClassName
```

**Working and expected results**

> ```
> MessageBodyClassName                  MessageCount 
> ------------------------------------- ------------ 
> HS.MESSAGE.GATEWAYREGISTRATIONREQUEST 0            
> HS.MESSAGE.MERGEPATIENTREQUEST        0            
> HS.MESSAGE.PATIENTSEARCHREQUEST       54
> ```

---

For VKP: **Why are the results different? How can I adjust the first query with literals to get the proper (same) results?**

Comment: I do not know your dbms. Whatever, the first thing i would check is the datatype of your column. If it's a char (and not a varcahr) you might have here the solutino of your problem

Comment: Is the type on the `messageBodyClassName` in `mh` a `varchar` or perhaps `char`?  Curious if it's an enumerated type and there for you're comparing 2 different types.  Your working query would preserve that.

Comment: It is a `VARCHAR`, according to DBVis and the ISC ODBC driver.

Comment: There's likely a blank or special (non display)  charcters in ens.messageheader.messageBodyClassName not in your hardcoded values.  To prove this out try to `SELECT count(*) from ens.messageheader where messageBodyClassName in ('HS.MESSAGE.GATEWAYREGISTRATIONREQUEST',
'HS.MESSAGE.MERGEPATIENTREQUEST',
'HS.MESSAGE.PATIENTSEARCHREQUEST')`  if your count is zero then the values in the table don't match your hardcoded ones. and you need to figure out why.  Try len to count characters or use ASCII to convert to asci character code to find out what is unexepected

Comment: `Aggregate_1: 117058`

Comment: @scott If both are identical. That doesnt make sense. The other thing is maybe you run the query in different time and that is why you get different results?

Comment: @xQbert he post a picture in my answer and they look identical.

Comment: @Scott I can't tell why you get different result, but if you say `DISTINCT` is slow, can you try create one `INDEX` for `MessageBodyClassName` ?

Comment: @JuancarlosOropeza I agree that screenshot seems to prove that the text in the two is identical.  Therefore the only other option is that it's different environment, different days or data get altered underneath him?  or uncommitted changes from something else.

Comment: Can we union the results of both queries and run them together (add a column called source with hardcoded values of QRYWORKS and QRYFAIL to appropriate queries and display the results.)  I want to eliminate environmental issues or uncommitted data.  the picture in Juan's answer doesn't have the limiting data criteria which could be causing 0 record counts...  What may have worked yesterday, may not work today due to changing dates on GETUTCDATE

Comment: Thanks for all the help everyone, even if it makes zero sense.  At least it doesn't seem to be me just [doing something stupid this time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40139867/complex-left-join-not-working-as-expected):)

Answer (score 2):

The last thing I can think of is to run your `DISTINCT` query once into a permanent table in your database.  That way the inner `SELECT` in your query will only have to process those three lines.  The inner query would lose `DISTINCT`, like

```
SELECT MessageBodyClassName FROM ens.messageheader_permvals
```

**EDIT**: The below answer did not work

This may be a longshot, but if it doesn't work it might help you diagnose the problem.  Instead of the `UNION` try

```
SELECT MessageBodyClassName FROM ens.messageheader
    WHERE MessageBodyClassName in (
    'HS.MESSAGE.GATEWAYREGISTRATIONREQUEST',        
    'HS.MESSAGE.MERGEPATIENTREQUEST',          
    'HS.MESSAGE.PATIENTSEARCHREQUEST')
```

That should return records only if those values actually exist in the table and are compatible with the format of `MessageBodyClassName`, which we know works using the `DISTINCT` version.  I don't know if the performance will be better this way, but hopefully it will shed some light on the issue.

**EDIT**: the below answer does not apply, as the OP is was actually trying to select the literal quoted values

You don't have a `FROM` statements in your UNION query.  Try

```
SELECT 'HS.MESSAGE.GATEWAYREGISTRATIONREQUEST' as MessageBodyClassName
            FROM ens.messageheader
        UNION SELECT 'HS.MESSAGE.MERGEPATIENTREQUEST'
            FROM ens.messageheader
        UNION SELECT 'HS.MESSAGE.PATIENTSEARCHREQUEST'
            FROM ens.messageheader
```

The rest of the query looks right.

Comment: You miss the question. and you dont need `FROM`

Comment: Without the `FROM` it took 27 seconds to execute.  With the `FROM` statements added, It took 90 and returned the same results. :(

Comment: If it helps I was really rooting for this answer!  :)

Comment: @Scott so are you trying to select the strings in quotes instead of columns with those names?  I assumed the quotes were a difference of intersystem-cache from the more general SQL I'm familiar with

Comment: Nope, I actually want those to be *values* of the column named `MessageBodyClassName`

Comment: @Scott so your UNION should return a little table with just three rows, one for each quoted value?

Comment: That's correct, and it does if I run it separately.

Comment: @Scott added another option to my answer

Comment: The query runs as expected and returns results... sadly it doesn't appear to be hidden characters or a type issue.

Comment: @Scott ok, one last idea added to answer

Comment: Unfortunately this is a hosted environment and that is not an option :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126349/discussion-between-rominus-and-scott).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with xQbert, problem is the hard codes values

Try

```
  SELECT T1.MessageBodyClassName, T2.MessageBodyClassName
  FROM (
          SELECT 'HS.MESSAGE.GATEWAYREGISTRATIONREQUEST' as MessageBodyClassName
    UNION SELECT 'HS.MESSAGE.MERGEPATIENTREQUEST'
    UNION SELECT 'HS.MESSAGE.PATIENTSEARCHREQUEST'
       ) as T1
 LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT DISTINCT(MessageBodyClassName) as MessageBodyClassName
         FROM ens.messageheader
       ) as T2
  ON T1.MessageBodyClassName = T2.MessageBodyClassName
```

Possible solution: Create a temporal table

```
 CREATE TABLE className as 
         SELECT DISTINCT(MessageBodyClassName) as MessageBodyClassName
         FROM ens.messageheader
```